# How can I unmount my Google Drive from Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have mounted my google drive contents into Google Colab via the command below:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Now, every time I create a new notebook the drive is automatically mounted. How can I unmount it?

Comment: Simply, do not run the code cell containg this code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

https://myaccount.google.com/permissions
Delete connect "Google Drive File Stream"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
from google.colab import drive

drive.flush_and_unmount
```

Answer (score 0):

Really?
In my code, I need some files from G. drive but every time I open the notebook it is unmounted so I should Go to the URL in a browser and Enter the authorization code.
I think you could reconnect to hosted runtime to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to "Factory Reset" the runtime in the cost of losing all variables from the workspace.